# Vue.Js Docker Variables

Tags: docker, vue.js

I have a static site Vue.Js docker image built on nginx:alpine.

In a component, there is a URL variable for an EndPoint - I would like to be able to change this variable. I understand that I only have access to ENV variables at the build stage after this everything is static.

What I want to achieve is being able to build 1 image: that I can deploy Test-Staging-Prod environments setting a different URL for each.

I can run a script that uses variable substitution on deploy that would replace the URL e.g #{url:urlEndpoint} in the js file (i can see it in plaintext) - but this is dangerous for the obvious reasons.

How can set this up and pass the url in Vue.Js without having different images for Test Staging etc?

Comment: Alternatively, you could check the URL in javascript and return the proper domain that way

Comment: Once you have deployed the images, can you know from within the component in which environment you are? If that is the case, there is any problem (or security concern) with having an object containing each URL?

Comment: @Ander The image could be deployed with different IP/domain/host name how would i know past the build stage that i am in a specific environment?

Comment: @Derek the URL/IP is agnostic host-name could be different as well. Is there anything i can do post build pre-deploy ?

Comment: @user685590, well, I dunno, maybe you have a shared volume in which you can include some info, maybe you can pass an environment variable when you launch the instance, maybe you have a script which is capable of determinate the environment according to some external information (network information, for example)

Comment: @Ander - The options seem to be limited for an agnostic approach, but found [this](https://www.georg-ledermann.de/blog/2018/04/27/dockerize-and-configure-javascript-single-page-application/) to be helpful. 
I had considered this but the implementation here isn't as messy as i'd expected: 
The other option is having a shared mapped drive on the container with the config file requested client side but this requires more manual setup for each deployment.